# (for letter in text: if letter == letter) what does this do?

Tags: python, if-statement

In a program used to count the number of repeated letters stored in a dictionary with the letter as the key and the count as the value, I do not understand how it works, especially in the `if y == y:` part since it doesn't make sense to me why it has to confirm why the same variable is equal to itself, this might just be a very stupid question, but I appreciate any explanation provided.

```
text = input()
dict = {}
#your code goes here
a = len(text) 
for x in range(a+1): 
    for y in text:
        if y == y: 
            dict[y] = text.count(y) 
print(dict)
```

I thought the `if y == y:` meant if the last letter is the same as the current letter, but I am not sure

Comment: `if y == y:` This is a useless statement.  It will always be true.  There is only one situation I'm aware of where a variable would not equal itself, and this ain't it.

Comment: If someone gave this code to you as an example to learn from, they did you a disservice.  There are a lot of things wrong with it besides the pointless `y == y` thing.

Comment: Okay. Let me guess, is the "for x in range(a+1):" also useless?

Comment: @JohnGordon it will not always be true. For example, it won't be true if `y = float('nan')`

Comment: anyway, regardless, a lot of this code doesn't make sense. If the goal is to get a count of the letters in a string, then it is also grossly inefficient.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Yes, that is exactly the one exception I had in mind.

Comment: the most basic way to count with a dict: `for x in whatever: mydict[x] = mydict.get(x, 0) + 1`

Comment: In this specific case, yes, `for x in range(a+1):` is also useless, because the `x` variable is not actually used in the loop.

Comment: @JohnGordon hey, you never know, the intention may have been to pointlessly add polynomial degree to the algorithmic complexity!

Comment: I love seeing experts chat